# Flutter push screen with pop animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

i have the code below and what i would like to achieve is to have an animation transition like 'pop' when calling 'push'. the code that i have just slides the new page from the direction that i specify. i would like to have the old screen be the one that is moving instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPageRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;
  final AxisDirection direction;

  CustomPageRoute({
    required this.child,
    required this.direction,
  }) : super(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => child,
        );

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) =>
      SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: getBeginOffset(), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(animation),
        child: child,
      );

  Offset getBeginOffset() {
    switch (direction) {
      case AxisDirection.up:
        return const Offset(0, 1);
      case AxisDirection.down:
        return const Offset(0, -1);
      case AxisDirection.right:
        return const Offset(-1, 0);
      case AxisDirection.left:
        return const Offset(1, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone looking to achieve the same thing, it can be achieved by using popUntil

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pageRouteBuilder with zero duration

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context, 
    PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => NewPage(),
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
    ),
);
```

Edit

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, anim, a2, child) => FadeTransition(opacity: anim, child: child),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
  ),
);
```

Comment: what if i would like to have the pop screen animation?